# How can I add class list items to listbox?

Tags: c#, list, listbox

So I have this namespace with two clases:

```
namespace Fonoteka1
{
public class Daina : IEquatable<Daina>
{
    public string vardas { get; set; }
    public int kodas { get; set; }
    public Daina()
    {
        vardas = "nėra dainų";
        kodas = 0;
    }
    public bool Equals(Daina other)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Vieta: " + vardas + " Kodas: " + kodas;
    }
    public string getVardas()
    {
        return vardas;
    }
    public int getKodas()
    {
        return kodas;
    }
}
public class Program
{

    [STAThread]
   static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());

        List<Daina> pradinis = new List<Daina>();
        List<Daina> antras = new List<Daina>();

        pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\R. City - Locked Away ft. Adam Levine.mp3", kodas = 125 });
        pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Californication.mp3", kodas = 1269 });
        pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\BWO - Sunshine In The Rain.mp3", kodas = 15 });
        pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\Cloud Atlas - Sextet.mp3", kodas = 89 });

}
}
}
```

and other namespace with form (GUI):

```
namespace Fonoteka
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {       
    } 
}
}
```

I want to print pradinis list (from Fonoteka1) in listbox1 (From Fonoteka), but I have no idea how(In listbox I cant reach pradinis list)? Also, when I clisk on a song from listbox, with button1 I want to get that songs code ( int kodas from Daina class)
Any help? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code after `Application.Run(new Form1());` will be executed after closing the form.

Please put the code of adding to list inside `Form1_Load`, and add to listbox1.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\R. City - Locked Away ft. Adam Levine.mp3", kodas = 125 });
    pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\Red Hot Chili Peppers - Californication.mp3", kodas = 1269 });
    pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\BWO - Sunshine In The Rain.mp3", kodas = 15 });
    pradinis.Add(new Daina { vardas = @"C:\Users\Gintarė\OneDrive\KTU paskaitos\5 semestras\Multimedijos sistemų projektavimas\Projektas\Fonoteka\Media\Cloud Atlas - Sextet.mp3", kodas = 89 });
    foreach (Diana d in pradinis)
        listBox1.Items.Add(d.vardas);
}
```

The variables should be defined as `Form1`'s variable

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Daina> pradinis = new List<Daina>();
    List<Daina> antras = new List<Daina>();
    ...
}
```

And for button text changing.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
        button1.Text = pradinis[listBox1.SelectedIndex].kodas.ToString();
    else
        button1.Text = "";
}
```

**Update:**

Seems that the list `antras` is for the selected songs, the code below adds the songs to `antras` when button1 is clicked.

(Use `Ctrl` and `Shift` to select multiple items in listbox)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
    ...
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    antras.Clear();
    foreach(int index in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
        antras.Add(pradinis[listBox1.SelectedIndex]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This realy hepled me!

Comment: @Haby You can accept the answer, if you think this really helped. :)

Comment: Maybe you also know how can I just receive code without showing it on button? I have to choose song and put selected song into new list

Comment: @Haby You can set `listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;` so you can select multiple songs by `Ctrl` and `Shift` without another listbox.

Comment: @Haby btw, you can upvote an answer or comment if you think it make use to you.

Comment: Not enought reputation for upvoting :(
I need to select one song and add it to another list, then select another and again add it to list (I have so select single songs). How to do this?
I also inserted in richtextbox:
      foreach (Daina d in antras)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = d.vardas2;
            }
But it does not print

Comment: You should `richTextBox1.Text = ""; foreach (Daina d in antras) { richTextBox1.Text += d.vardas2; }`